# Fetch mysql data of timstamp depending on time given

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with timestamp, contain example value "2014-04-16 18:00:00","2014-04-17 18:00:00"....

Now, if I will call a page **before**  "2014-04-17 12:00:00" I need this value-"2014-04-16 18:00:00"
And if I call my page **after** "2014-04-17 12:00:00" I need this value "2014-04-17 18:00:00".

I think my question is very complicated to understand, having complications in date & times, please check date & time properly.

I want to fetch this data from DB in mysql, The page I was saying is that where I'm going to add your mysql query.

Thanx in advance

Comment: how, can you please give example

Comment: Are you trying to find highest value that is less than something else? e.g. highest date/time that is before current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalising what your asking for a bit the following will return dates from the previous day if it's before noon and dates from today if it's after noon:

```
SELECT date_column
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)) = DATE(date_column);
```

Edit:

The WHERE clause First gets the current time (`NOW()`) and subtracts 12 hours. This wont affect the date unless the time is before 12. This means `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)` gives us today if it's after noon and yesterday if it's before.

We then check if the date_column matches the date we've created (using the `DATE` function so that the time is ignored).

Adding some rows to the SELECT may help you see how these dates are built up.

Comment: i rly thanx full of you, but can you please explain this query.

Comment: @Amol Certainly, I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thnx for your explanation.